# How to convert a string to a variable name in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, object, global

I have a list of two strings:

```
x = ['feature1','feature2']
```

I need to create the following list `y` from the list `x`:

```
y = [feature1, feature2]
```

How can I do that in Python?

Comment: No, is not possible and it doesn't make sense. What would be the point? This goes against the python principles of simplicity. Better use a container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could directly put the variables into `globals`:

```py
x = ['feature1','feature2']

for varname in x:
    globals()[varname] = 123

print(feature1)
# 123
```

This will allow creating `y` as specified in the question.

The fact that it's possible, however, doesn't indicate that it should be done this way. Without knowing specifics of the problem you are solving, it's difficult to advise further, but there might be a better way to achieve what you are after.

Update: in a comment @mozway raised some concerns with the above, one of which was that `y` will not be modified if, for example, feature2 is modified. For example:

```py
x = ['feature1','feature2']

for varname in x:
    globals()[varname] = 123

y = [feature1, feature2]
print(y)
# [123, 123]

feature2 = 456
print(y)
# [123, 123]
```

This seems like a useful thing to keep in mind, albeit even with regular syntax I get a similar behaviour:

```py
feature1 = 123
feature2 = 123
y = [feature1, feature2]
print(y)
# [123, 123]

feature2 = 456
print(y)
# [123, 123]
```

Comment: This doesn't make it a list of "pointers" like OP seems to want.

Comment: Hmm, can you elaborate? Are you saying there should be a line with `y = [feature1, feature2]` or something else? (not that familiar with Python, so I might be missing something)

Comment: What I mean is 1- you should really not define globals (unless being a really advanced user and writing a low level library), 2- if you create globals from `x`, then create `y`, then modify the `feature1` variable, `y` will remain unchanged. It's not acting like a pointer like OP seems to want.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, I updated the answer. Though I am not sure what OP wants (pointers or not), so I assume they will test the code and come back if this functionality is not sufficient for their use case.

Answer (score 2):

Just for syntactical purposes here a possibility with [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec). Remember that it accepts extra parameters to restrict the scope of the variables (default is global).

```
x = ['feature1','feature2']

for s in x:
    exec(f'{s} = "{s}"') # execute the string containing a python command

y = [feature1, feature2]
print(y)
#['feature1', 'feature2']
```